# Query firestore array of objects

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have firestore collection ***events***.

Every ***event*** have ***date*** which is array of objects with two strings, ***startTime*** and ***endTime***.

[image]

Is it possibile to retrive every ***events*** which have at list one ***startTime*** which is bigger than current time?

Comment: Have a look at this documentation item, it may help: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/arrays

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not possible with your document structure.  You can't target array elements in queries.  Instead, you may want to store the max startTime as a top-level field in the document, and use that instead in your queries instead.

Duplicating data like this to suit your queries is common.  With NoSQL databases, the structure of your data should always follow the queries you intend to make.

Comment: Is this still the case? I need to do basically the same thing as OP. I have multiple dates in the array and need to find the ones that are in the past. It doesn't make sense to store individual dates at the top level of the document. Any workaround, please?

Answer (score 6):

You can get the whole document by querying firebase with "array-contains", but you must search for the exact properties of the object and the exact object itself. In your case "endTime" and "startTime".

```
firebase.firestore.collection('events').where("date", "array-contains", {endTime: "March 18 ....", startTime: "March 19 ...."})
```

Comment: This actually works. Google should think of an easier way to do this. Sometimes the whole object can vary :S